# Getting the X and Y position of the mouse when it is clicked on the image in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon, null-layout-manager

I have a Image displayed inside JLabel using ImageIcon feature.

The JLabel is contained inside a JPanel.

When image is clicked, I want to get the mouse position relative to the image.

I am trying to solve this problem by adding mouse listener to the JLabel which contains the 
image.

Apparently, even if I set the size of JLabel with the width and height of the image, it seems that JLabel automatically stretches out to the size of JPanel.

So when below code runs, if the size of image is smaller than the JPanel, getting X and Y position returns the unwanted value.

Is there a way that I can specifically limit the size of the JLabel so that getting X position and Y position of the mouse will work fine?

Or better way to get a mouse position relative to the image? (which would be better)

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);

    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(icon);
    imageLabel.setSize(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));

    imageLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(imageLabel, e.getX()+" "+e.getY());
        }
    });

    imageLabel.validate();
    panel.add(imageLabel);
    panel.validate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all about the layout.

[image]

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180198/centering-a-jlabel-on-a-jpanel/7181197#7181197) for the above image.

---

It would seem this use-case requires a [`GridBagLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) or [`BoxLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your probably seeing problems because the Layout manager is controlling the size of your label, not the setSize() call.

I'd probably create my a JPanel derived class (instead of a JLabel) that implements paintComponent by drawing the image. Then i'd override getPreferredSize() and getMaximumSize() of the JPanel to return the dimensions of the image.

Using the label will cause troubles because there's going to be padding, offsets and such.

Comment: If overriding `paintComponent()` and there is no need to add further components, a `JComponent` provides almost as much functionality as a `JPanel`.  Either way for this use-case, I'd still opt for a label in a panel using the right layout.

Comment: (nearly duplicate answers?) 0) The last paragraph in the other ist dead on point (layoutManager rules) as is the first. The stuff in between is .. not so good: 1) there doesn't seem to be any need for extending just for showing the icon 2) if there is a need - f.i. have use the panel in its natural role as a container and show a background image - then overriding the getPref/Max could (and probably should) be done, but doesn't help (see bullet 0) 3) no problem with "padding and such" in a plain label with icon, null text and empty border .. no wild guesses, please :-)

Answer (score 1):

`it seems that JLabel automatically stretches out to the size of JPanel.`

problem is here

```
imageLabel.setSize(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
```

if is there only one `JLabel`, then

```
myPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());//JPanel has by default FlowLayout
myPanel.add(myLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER)
```

if is there more that one JLabel with Image/IconImage and should be better look for GridLayout

EDIT

in all cases (for reall picture) before anything

1) you have to determine picture ratio 3:2, 4:3 16:10 ..., determine CropRatio then you have to :

- setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x/cropRatio, y/cropRatio)) for JLabel
- by using [paintComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) g2d.fillRect(0, 0, x/cropRatio, y/cropRatio);

2) put JLabel to the [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), but then will be hold original amout of pixels

Comment: If myPanel has only 1 component, it seems that that component gets stretched out :(

Answer (score 0):

Your probably seeing problems because the Layout manager is controlling the size of your label, not the setSize() call.

I'd probably create my a JPanel derived class (instead of a JLabel) that implements paintComponent by drawing the image. Then i'd override getPreferredSize() and getMaximumSize() of the JPanel to return the dimensions of the image.

Using the label will cause troubles because there's going to be padding and such.

But in the end, what's causing our label to expand is the layout manager. Most like the easiest way to do what you want is to make sure your layout manager isn't expanding the label, by picking a layout manager that keeps the component at it's preferred size.