# Set component at center of the page

Tags: java, swing, flowlayout

How can I set a component (say button) at center of the panel?
I used `Flowlayout` with layout constraint as center, but I am getting button at **top-center** position of the panel.

Answer (score 10):

This can be achieved using either [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) as [mentioned by AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9090645/418556)<sup>1</sup> or [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) for sample code.

[image]

Personally I'd use GBL for this because fewer lines of code are required to get the component laid out & on-screen (centered in the parent container).

1. I do not understand why that answer is not getting more up-votes, but that aside..

Comment: +1 for this and this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271

Comment: @AVD It's one of my favorite answers.  Especially because of the pretty screen-shots supplied by trashgod (I often borrow them for illustrating points in other threads).  Really rounds it out nicely.  :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `GridBagLayout` instead of FlowLayout.

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
panel.add(new JButton("Sample")); // will use default value of GridBagConstraints
```

Comment: The first 2 lines can be written as one.  +1  (one of the few things for which I [use GBL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `null` layout and set the button's bounds, like this:

```
// assuming you're extending JPanel
private JButton button; // data field

...

this.setLayout(null);
this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){
   public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
       setButtonBounds();
   }
});

private void setButtonBounds(){
   int bw = 90; // button width
   int bh = 30; // button height
   int w = getWidth();
   int h = getHeight();
   button.setBounds((w - bw) / 2, (h - bh) / 2, bw, bh);
}
```

If you start getting many buttons or a complex layout, consider using [MigLayout](http://miglayout.com).

Comment: -1 for even suggesting a `null` layout.   Edit that out & I will remove the down-vote (but I am not giving an up-vote for `MigLayout`, when there are 2 J2SE layouts that can do what is required).

Comment: I've never really understood why `null` layout is so bad, but fair enough. I'll leave my answer and accept the -1.

Comment: See [setLayout(null) is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374) for my comments (some uncharitable people might call it a 'rant') on the subject.

Comment: Won't start arguing here, but I agree with many of the arguments against banishing `null` layout / absolute positioning. AP definitely has a place in GUI design, and because many solutions to a problem are perfectly valid, they're equally correct if the effect is the same.

Comment: Sure, but why not encapsulate that logic into a layout  (wherein it becomes unnecessary to call `setLayout(null)`?   Even your example above could (both be improved and) be better encapsulated in a layout.  It seems to make sense to do it inline in the code until you require a 2nd (3rd ..17th) instance of 'center a component', which is a pretty basic requirement BTW.  As to the comment that it can 'be improved'.  Why hard-code the widths of the button when there is `getPreferredSize()` (which takes into account the current button text, borders, PLAF,..)?  Almost a **classic e.g.** of my point!

Comment: +1 for making good sense, and I actually do agree with you. It does seem redundant to nullify the layout and set the bounds manually. I think it comes down to a lack of understanding of how the core layout managers actually function. So I agree that a manager / encapsulation is better, but they would still both be right answers and I wouldn't -1 someone for suggesting an appropriate (perhaps silly) use of a `null` layout. Again, I don't think this is the place for this discussion, so I'll end things there. Thanks though.