# Is there any way to make JPanel responsible or auto resizable (row coding not using drag and drop) in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7I80.jpg]

In the picture black color is `JFrame`, cyan color is `JPanel`.

At first, I set `JFrame` size (500,500), and a `JPanel` whose width is the same as the `JFrame` width but whose height is 10 and it works well. When I increased the `JFrame` size as like monitor size, I want to increase `JPanel` size automatically, however `JPanel` width was not increased. What should I do? Or should I make `JFrame.setResizable(false)`?

Comment: I suspect you meant [« responsive »](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

Comment: You could use some kind of proportional layout.  `GridBagLayout` can do this, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922807/resizable-window-with-3-proportional-panels/26923195#26923195) or, if you're up for a challenge, you could always [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635952/java-layout-proportions-creating-a-scalable-square-panel/14636828#14636828)

Comment: Create two `JPanels`.  The first `JPanel` is your cyan `JPanel`.  Set the preferred size to 500, 10.  The second `JPanel` is your black `JPanel`.  Set the preferred size to 500, 490.  Place the cyan `JPanel` in the `JFrame` NORTH and place the black `JPanel` in the `JFrame` CENTER.  Instead of setting the size of the `JFrame`, pack it.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.