# Put a JButton in the center of the screen with BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

How to add a **JButton** into the center of a JFrame with `BorderLayout()`? I tried using `BorderLayout.CENTER`, but instead of the center of the screen, it gave the top-center of the screen. Or do I have to use another layout manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `JPanel` in the `CENTER` and set the layout to `GridBagLayout` or `BoxLayout` as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) to [Set component at center of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9090609/418556).

[image]

The `GridBagLayout` is used to center a label containing the yellow/red gradient image seen in the [Nested Layout Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).

[image: Animated image of nested layout example showing size change]

Comment: @camickr  Yes, it is the type of one-liner 'add as single component with no constraint' that I especially like.

Comment: @Craig  Yes, at just 55 LOC, it is one of my favorite SSCCEs.  :)

Answer (score 1):

It may take some time to learn, but [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) is worth looking into. It will let you position elements on the GUI where you wish. You can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for examples of different layouts.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: But that will stretch the component (in this case a `JButton`) to the size of the container as seen in the screenshot below.  This use-case sounds more like 'center with white space around component'.

Comment: *"as seen in the screenshot.."* ..in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16727593/418556).