# how to put JLabel center of the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, layout-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Centering a JLabel on a JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180198/centering-a-jlabel-on-a-jpanel)

i want to put JLabel in to the center of JPanel. i have used below code so can you just tell me. what is wrong with this code?
code :

```
public class ColoredRect extends JPanel{

      public double x, y, width, height;  
      public JLabel name;

      public ColoredRect(double x,double y,String label)
      {

          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.width = 100;
          this.height =40;

          setLocation((int)x,(int)y);
          setSize((int)width,(int)height);
          setBackground(Color.red);

          name = new JLabel(label,JLabel.CENTER);
          name.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
          name.setVisible(true);
          name.setSize(20,20);
          name.repaint();
          add(name);
        }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Also consider learning about [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)'s instead of positioning components yourself with setLocation/setSize/setBounds

Answer (score 2):

Use BorderLayout with center attribute, if JLabel is the only component in the container (ie JPanel here) then if the BorderLayout is used, then its by default center. **Its better you go with GroupLayout, developed by netbeans team in 2005.**

eg:

```
class pan extends JPanel{

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Name");

        public void go(){

            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `GridLayout` is easier (shorter).  See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) for two other layouts.

Comment: thanks for quick reply vivek, but i have used borderlayout. it's not coming in center

Comment: To repeat, **for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the horizontal alignment also:

```
name.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```