# Images in paintComponent only show up after resizing the window

Tags: java, image, swing, paint

I want to use `paintComponent(Graphics g)` to paint a few images using a for loop. However, the JFrame just shows up as a white screen, and it only shows the black background and the images after I resize the window.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*; 
import javax.imageio.*; 
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class SimpleAdventure {
         private JFrame frame;
         private CardLayout cards;
         private Container c;
         private DrawPanel1 gamepanel;
         private BufferedImage greentiles, pinktiles, sandtiles, charsprites;
         private Image left1, right1, left2, right2, front;
         private Image pinkbg, greenbg, sandbg;
         private Image pinktop, greentop, sandtop;
         private int charx, chary;

         public SimpleAdventure()
         {}
         public static void main (String [] args)
         {
                 SimpleAdventure retro = new SimpleAdventure();
                 retro.run();
         }
         public void run()
         {
                 frame = new JFrame("Simple Adventure");
                 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                 frame.setSize(576, 576);
                 frame.setVisible(true);
                 // frame.setResizable(false);
                 getImage();


                 c = frame.getContentPane();
                 cards = new CardLayout();
                 c.setLayout(cards);

                 gamepanel = new DrawPanel1();
                 gamepanel.setBackground(Color.black);
                 c.add(gamepanel, "Panel 1");
         }
         public void getImage()
         {

             try
             {
                 greentiles = ImageIO.read(new File("greenTiles.png"));
                 pinktiles = ImageIO.read(new File("pinkTiles.png"));
                 sandtiles = ImageIO.read(new File("sandTiles.png"));
                 charsprites = ImageIO.read(new File("charactersheet.png"));
             }
             catch(IOException e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }


             left1 = charsprites.getSubimage(18, 0, 6, 6);
             left2 = charsprites.getSubimage(24, 0, 6, 6);
             right1 = charsprites.getSubimage(0, 0, 6, 6);
             right2 = charsprites.getSubimage(6, 0, 6, 6);
             front = charsprites.getSubimage(12, 0, 6, 6);

             greenbg = greentiles.getSubimage(240, 0, 16, 16);
             sandbg = sandtiles.getSubimage(240, 0, 16, 16);
             pinkbg = pinktiles.getSubimage(240, 0, 16, 16);

             greentop = greentiles.getSubimage(224, 0, 16, 16);
             sandtop = sandtiles.getSubimage(224, 0, 16, 16);
             pinktop = pinktiles.getSubimage(224, 0, 16, 16);
         }

         class DrawPanel1 extends JPanel implements KeyListener
         {
                 // private BottomPanel lower;
                 public DrawPanel1()
                 {
                     /*this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                     lower = new BottomPanel();
                     this.add(lower, BorderLayout.SOUTH);*/
                     addKeyListener(this);
                 }

                 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
                 {
                         super.paintComponent(g);

                         for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                         {
                             g.drawImage(greentop, 0 + (i * 96), 480, 96, 96, this);
                         }
                         System.out.println("check");
                 }
                 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
                 {

                 }
                 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
                 {

                 }
                 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
                 {

                 }
         } }
```

Comment: `frame.setSize(576, 576);`  That is odd.  I'd have thought you'd want the `Simple Adventure` to be square rather than the frame that contains it.  To make the adventure game area square, either set a preferred size or override it to return a square preferred size.  The `pack()` the frame to have it automatically sized to fit the components within it.  See also [`SquarePanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16868332/418556) for a demo of a component that retains a square shape but stretches to fit the parent.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `frame.pack()` to do the initial layout. Resizing the window automatically causes the layout to be fixed, but `frame.setSize(...)` does not*.

Move `frame.setVisible(true)` to the end of your `run` method (i.e. after you've constructed all the UI elements) and put `frame.pack()` just before `frame.setVisible(true)`. (Thanks Hovercraft and MadProgrammer for pointing this out)

*At least, it doesn't if the frame is not visible. It might work if the frame is already visible; try it and see.

EDIT: Now that I re-read the javadoc, you probably don't want `pack` after all - it will resize the frame for you. Without testing it, I guess that moving `setVisible` to the end will work; if it doesn't then use `revalidate` rather than `pack` to get the layout engine to run.

EDIT 2: Now that I re-re-read the javadoc, `setVisible` will validate the window if it is not already displayable. So you won't need an explicit call to `revalidate`. `setSize` will *invalidate* the component but will not *revalidate* it.

TL;DR: It's worth reading up on how validation and displayability work in Swing so you don't make the mistakes I just did.

Answer (score 3):

Call `setVisible` only after you have built the UI...

```
public void run()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Simple Adventure");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(576, 576);
    // frame.setResizable(false);
    getImage();


    c = frame.getContentPane();
    cards = new CardLayout();
    c.setLayout(cards);

    gamepanel = new DrawPanel1();
    gamepanel.setBackground(Color.black);
    c.add(gamepanel, "Panel 1");

    // Lucky last...   
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Otherwise you will need to revalidate the frame