# Adding panel in center of container

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have a `JPanel` which is a `BorderLayout` and I have  set a new panel in the top and container (`JDesktopPane`) in center and another panel in bottom. Now I want to set  panel (card layout) dynamically in center of container as I am showing  hierarchy below

```
           top --> panel
panel(BorderLayout)center --> container(JDesktopPane) --> panel(CardLayout)
            bottom --> panel
```

Here card layout contain different panel as card. problem is that I'm unable to show each card in center of container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to show them center of container?

Put them in a panel with a `GridBagLayout`, add them as the only component with no constraint, and they will be centered.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) for an example.

[image]

Comment: thanks and +1 for and quick reply and useful ink. i will give a try

Answer (score -1):

**-** `GroupLayout` provides a hassle free way arranging the components as you want them too.

**-** `GroupLayout` was developed by `NetBeans` Group in 2005.

**-** You can download the `Windows Builder Pro` for free from Google, and use it.