# How to add JToolBar in center of JPanel ,Java Swing?

Tags: swing, jpanel, border-layout, jtoolbar

I am new to Java Swing.I want to design one `JToolBar`. The `JToolBar` should be placed in center of `JPanel`.  Is it possible?

```
javax.swing.JPanel pane = new javax.swing.JPanel(); 
BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout(); 
pane.setLayout(border); 
JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar(); 
pane.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.CENTER); 
javax.swing.JButton button1 = new javax.swing.JButton("Click Me"); 
toolBar.add(button1);
```

Comment: If you have tried using _BorderLayout_ then post that code else it will be very hard to guess.

Comment: 1) See [Centering a JLabel on a JPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) for tips.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about [How to use ToolBars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html).

The following code is taken straight from the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html).

```
public ToolBarDemo() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    ...
    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("Still draggable");
    addButtons(toolBar);
    ...
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 130));
    add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

See the usage of `BorderLayout`  here. And do the necessary changes in your code.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried using your code which shows output like this. I have used [addSeparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html#addSeparator%28%29) method with dimension. `This is just a try to solve the problem. I am not sure whether this approach is the correct way.`

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 
    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar(); 
    panel.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    toolBar.addSeparator(new Dimension(150, 0));

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Click Me"); 
    toolBar.add(button1);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I too got same result while I try my code.Is it possible to display that 'click me' button in center position of the toolbar?

Comment: @boopathy  Look at my update. I used addSeparator to do this. I am not sure whether this is a right approach or not. This will solve your purpose. But make sure you know the right way of doing this and please let me know.

Comment: @boopathy In _JPanel_ we have added _JToolBar_. But the _Button_ is inside the toolbar. So we have to align the button which is in the JToolBar. But I have read the doc it does not have any layout inside JToolBar. So I have added an _addSeparator_ with width of 150 with respect to my frame dimension. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you `JPanel` has a `BorderLayout` and you place the `JToolBar` in `BorderLayout.CENTER` and you have components in `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST` and `WEST` then I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I too tried that way, but that didn't worked ,that's why posted this question.

Comment: Hard to guess what "didn't work" means in your case. Post some code, screenshots, whatever you have.

Comment: `javax.swing.JPanel pane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
pane.setLayout(border);
JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
pane.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.CENTER);
javax.swing.JButton button1 = new javax.swing.JButton("Click Me");
toolBar.add(button1);`

Comment: As I said, add stuff to the other parts of the UI, not just in the center.

Comment: I tried all possibilities(BorderLayout.CENTER instead of BorderLayout.NORTH or EAST or WEST or SOUTH).All are produced same output only.

Comment: You must add the toolbar to CENTER and add other panels, even empty to the other parts.