# How do I keep a JButton from changing size?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a simple game where you can set out tiles that make up a celtic design and I can't seem to make the buttons stay the same size. Here's the code:

```
public class CTGContent {

    public static JPanel content = new JPanel();
    private static JButton board[][] = new JButton[20][20];

    static private Random random = new Random();

    public static int CTGcolumn = random.nextInt(14)+1;
    public static int CTGRow = 15;
    private static GridLayout boardLayout;

    public final int getBoardWidth(){
        return CTGcolumn*40;
    }

    public final int getBoardHeight(){
        return CTGRow*40;
    }

    public static void initializeBoard(){
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        int defaultCOL = 0;
        int defaultROW = 0;

        boardLayout = new GridLayout(CTGRow, CTGcolumn);
        content.setLayout(boardLayout);

        Random determine = new Random(); 

        while (row < CTGRow){
            column = 0;
            while (column < CTGcolumn){
                board[row][column] = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images\\template.gif"));
                board[row][column].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
                board[row][column].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
                board[row][column].setMinimumSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
                content.add(board[row][column]);
                column++;
            }
            row++;
        }
    }

    private static void build(){

        initializeBoard();

        JFrame window = new JFrame("testing the menubar");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setContentPane(content);
        content.add(new JLabel("My Label"));
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);    

    }

    public CTGContent() {

    }

    public CTGContent(JFrame window){

        initializeBoard();
        window.add(content);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    build();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It starts off the right size usually but then for some reason if I resize the window or something they change size with it. I need them to stay the same size no matter what. How can I do that?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, *select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.*

Comment: Note that the linked 'duplicate' is most definitely **not**.  The linked question wanted to keep a group of buttons the same size as *each other*, and the answer was `GridLayout`.  This question already used `GridLayout` but wanted to keep the buttons the same size *when the window resized* and the answer was put the entire panel into a parent panel that respects the size of the content and won't resize it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
window.setContentPane(content);
```

To:

```
JPanel contentCenter = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
contentCenter.add(content);
window.setContentPane(contentCenter);
```

[image]

[image]

There are other ways to do it, like make the layout a `FlowLayout`, but the GBL will keep it nicely centered - both vertically and horizontally.

### Tips

1. Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.
2. For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That code only needed import in order to make it an MCVE.
3. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) to [Centering a JLabel on a JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7180198/418556)

[image]

Comment: @alesc3 I did not down vote your answer, and *I'll prove it if you like.*

Answer (score 0):

You use `GridLayout` because of your buttons resize horisontally/vertically always to fill whole grid cell. To prevent that you can use another `LayoutManager`, for example [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Always read about [setting size to components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi).

Comment: It is not actually necessary to change the layout from `GridLayout`.  Just constraining the entire panel *inside* a `GridBagLayout` will do.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, oh really, you are right. Topic starter can wrap his panel to not resizable LayoutManager.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Thompson. That helped a lot :D