# Setting Layout to JPanel resets Buttons

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

This is the result i want : https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9xWD.jpg  , but centered using BorderLayout. Instead, i get this :https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXJgp.jpg  . So, basically setting a layout resets my background and puts the button on the whole frame:

```
frame.setContentPane(new Pane());
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
```

I've also tried this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(bStart);
add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

But it doesn't work.

```
public class Pane extends JPanel{
    public Pane(){
        ImageIcon start = new ImageIcon("Start.png");
        ImageIcon startroll = new ImageIcon("Start-Hover.png");
        ImageIcon startselect = new ImageIcon("Start-Pressed.png");

        JButton bStart = new JButton(start);


        Insets margin = new Insets(-10,-10,-10,-10);
        bStart.setMargin(margin);
        bStart.setRolloverEnabled(true);
        bStart.setRolloverIcon(startroll);
        bStart.setPressedIcon(startselect);
        bStart.setBorderPainted(false);


        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(bStart, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: *"This is the result i want : http://imgur.com/tGleIly , but centered using BorderLayout."*  Use a `GridBagLayout` to center a component.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) for an example.

Comment: setting the layout before, has no effect.

Comment: @zaa, the GridBagLayout will work. If you have a problem then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
frame.getContentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

Comment: @zaa yes, sorry... Derp.

Comment: Doesn't that just centre it horizontally and not vertically?

Comment: @MadProgrammer from the image op posted that's what it seems he wants to do.

Comment: That's all fine then ;)

Comment: After the image, i said " but centered" also vertically , just like borderlayout does.

Comment: @zaa   centered on the x and y axis? Am I understanding you  correctly?

Comment: Yes, ccentered on x and y axis