# How to set object in center of frame?

Tags: java, swing, layout, border

I am new with programming. I am not sure how to put an object in the center of a frame. This is how far i got:

```
public class LetSee extends JPanel {

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

          int row;   // Row number, from 0 to 7
          int col;   // Column number, from 0 to 7
          int x,y;   // Top-left corner of square
          for ( row = 0;  row < 5;  row++ ) {

             for ( col = 0;  col < 5;  col++) {
                x = col * 60;
                y = row * 60;
                if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) )
                   g.drawRect(x, y, 60, 60);

                else
                   g.drawRect(x, y, 60, 60);

             } 

          } // end for row

      }
 }



public class LetSeeFrame extends JFrame {

    public LetSeeFrame(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1900, 1000);
        setVisible(true);
        LetSee let = new LetSee();
        let.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(let,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LetSeeFrame l = new LetSeeFrame();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 'centre' as in border layout, or 'centre' as in the geometric actual centre?

Comment: Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent` before you doing any custom painting, strange things will start doing wrong if you don't. Also `paintComponent` doesn't need to `public`, no one should ever call it directly

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) - but that depends on the custom component returning a logical preferred size.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : You're right, I quoted your comment in the answer .

Comment: @SteveSmith actually as border layout...sry but Barger had good solution to,but is hard to manage.. :/ I am learning this for now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your panel is centered in the frame, but what it draws isn't.

You should make use of the `width` and the `height` of the `JPanel` to center the drawing .

Also put your sizes and numbers into variables, it is less error-prone when you use them several times in your code .

Finally as @MadProgrammer said in the comments :

> Don't forget to call super.paintComponent before you doing any custom
>   painting, strange things will start doing wrong if you don't. Also
>   paintComponent doesn't need to be public, no one should ever call it
>   directly

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LetSee extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        int row; // Row number, from 0 to 7
        int col; // Column number, from 0 to 7
        int x, y; // Top-left corner of square

        int maxRows = 5;
        int maxCols = 5;

        int rectWidth = 60;
        int rectHeight = 60;

        int maxDrawWidth = rectWidth * maxCols;
        int maxDrawHeight = rectHeight * maxRows;

        // this is for centering :
        int baseX = (getWidth() - maxDrawWidth) / 2;
        int baseY = (getHeight() - maxDrawHeight) / 2;

        for (row = 0; row < maxRows; row++) {

            for (col = 0; col < maxCols; col++) {
                x = col * rectWidth;
                y = row * rectHeight;
                if ((row % 2) == (col % 2)) {
                    g.drawRect(baseX + x, baseY + y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
                } else {
                    g.drawRect(baseX + x, baseY + y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
                }

            }

        } // end for row

    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Tnx <3 :D You saved me a lot of time :)