# How do I put a JPanel in center of a JFrame irrespective the size of JFrame (of course its size is greater than jpanel)?

Tags: java, swing

Here I'm giving you the code written in the constructor of my JFrame . I've used `BorderLayout.CENTER` to put my JPanel in the center of JFrame but it's not working.

```
public FrameExamine() {
   initComponents();
   PanelExamine panelExamine=new PanelExamine();
   setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   getContentPane().add(panelExamine , BorderLayout.CENTER);
   // pack();
   setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: What part of your code isn't putting the panel in the center of the frame?  If you mean that `panelExamine` is been resized when the frame is resized, then wrap `panelExamine` in another panel, which is using a `GridBagLayout` and put that onto the frame instead

Comment: It will be best if in addition to 'not working', you would give some details on what does happen.

Comment: I am about to close this as a duplicate, but note that the [best answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) on the duplicate question is my own. It's just not the 'accepted' answer. :P